# jQuery Datepicker without trigger

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want a jQuery 3 months calendar to be shown on the page. User will select some date and click on a button to view the schedules.

I tried with below jQuery code

```
<input type="text" id="dp-text-box" />

$("#dp-text-box").datepicker({               
            numberOfMonths: 3,               
            dateFormat:'yy/mm/dd'
        });
```

However it will show the textbox and user has to click to open datepicker.

But in my case i should show the datepicker default and allow the user to navigate.

Please find the attached image that i need.[image: My Date Picker Requirement]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual,

> Display the datepicker embedded in the page instead of in an overlay. Simply call .datepicker() on a div instead of an input

HTML

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onSelect : function( selDate, instance){
        alert(selDate);
    }
});
```

Note: `onSelect` bit not tested, but should work.

Comment: This worked like charm! Thanks. But how we get the selected date without a textbox? I want the selected date to process.

Comment: You can still have the `onSelect` event on this datepicker. Let me know if you can take care of it, or need some pointers on how it is done

Comment: Sure i will be taking care of this with some hidden field and setting the value in onSelect event. If i am wrong you can correct me !

Answer (score 0):

Use div instead of textbox

javascript

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

html

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```